# JavaScript loading order

Tags: 7, javascript

I've installed eu-cookie-compliance module in few projects and everywhere it worked as expected but in one project I have problems with loading JavaScript in correct order.
Even if I implement hook_js_alter and set higher weights, eu-compliance JavaScript is loaded before misc/drupal.js and misc/jquery.js. Is there any better way to reorder this JavaScript?

Answer (score 9):

You could always change the group it's in:

```
function MYMODULE_js_alter(&$js) {
  $js['path/to/eu-cookie-compliance.js']['group'] = JS_DEFAULT;
}
```

Drupal's misc JS, jQuery etc, should all be in `JS_SYSTEM`, which has a lower weighting than `JS_DEFAULT`. There's also `JS_THEME` which has a height weighting than `JS_DEFAULT`.

The [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) docs discuss the whole JS weighting thing in much greater detail.

Comment: I tried everything what you wrote. I even set group and weight in drupal_add_js - no result.

Comment: Any chance you've got another module on that site interfering with the JS? I use that method in pretty much every site (and all of those have the eu cookie module installed) to reduce the number of aggregated JS files and it's never failed to work. You might try setting `$js['path/to/eu-cookie-compliance.js']['every_page'] = TRUE;` as a test as well

Comment: No, still not working.

Comment: Have you confirmed the same behaviour on a blank install of Drupal? It would rule out your specific site instance being the problem at least

Comment: That's the oddest think, I have used this module on Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 installation, but only here eu-cookie-compliance.js is outputted at the beginning of $scripts variable.

Comment: There must be something different about the JS on that site. It's very difficult to track something like that down without disabling modules systematically :/